# How to pass value to the second page using Javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an html select on my page

```
<pre>
$query = mysql_query("select * from results");
echo "<select id='date' onchange='showdata()' class='form-control'>";
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<option value=".$arr['month'].">".$arr['month']." / ".$arr['year']. "</option>" ;   
}
echo "</select>";
</pre>
```

the options are coming from database. After this I have ajax script

```
<script>

function showdata() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "result.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

I want it to send the selected value in the html select to the page result.php

Comment: You have a problem here, all months of different years will result in the same value for the `select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way of doing the same thing using jquery ajax ...

```
<select id="item" onchange="send_item(this.value)">
 <?php $someVariable = $_GET["someVariable"];
       $query = mysql_query("select * from results");
       echo "";
     while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo your value?>"><?php echo your value?></option>
   <?php }?>
</select>



  <script>
  function send_item(str){
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: "post",
        data: {
           'str':str,
        },
        success: function(data) {

        },
    });
 }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$someVariable = $_GET["someVariable"];
$query = mysql_query("select * from results");
        echo "";
        while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "".$arr['month']." / ".$arr['year']. "" ;

        }
        echo "";
```

And JS:

```
<script>

function showdata() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "result.php?someVariable=test", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

If you need example for POST, visit [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-using-an-xmlhttprequest)